# Does Koji Kashin have memories of his original?

Tags: boruto

Not sure if it's been revealed in the anime already, but we know (spoilers)

> Koji Kashin (果心居士, Kashin Koji) is a clone of Jiraiya that was created by Amado for the purpose of killing Isshiki Ōtsutsuki. [Koji Kashin](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Koji_Kashin)

But how does he know how to perform the same techniques than the original if apparently nobody taught them how to do them?

Does Koji Kashin have memories of his original?

Comment: logically I believe he used to have memories of his original because he got all the Jutsu of Jiraiya, maybe he is working like anbu to safe hidden leaf by killing jigen otsuki. the main reason he was hiding his connection with leaf village is to hide his identity inside kara.

Comment: along with what @SayedMohdAli said, considering Naruto's shadow clones hold the same chakra/knowledge as the original, it wouldn't be a far stretch to assume that Kashin Koji holds the memories of Jiraiya, as Orochimaru explained that most *created* clones (like Shin Uchiha for example) are practically eternal shadow clones until they are killed.